# Problem with building heatmap based on pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which has a lot of columns, I will show only important/related columns in this question:

```
data[['HomePlanet', 'CryoSleep', 'Transported']].head()
```

```
 HomePlanet CryoSleep   Transported
0   Europa  False   False
1   Earth   False   True
2   Europa  False   False
3   Europa  False   False
4   Earth   False   True
```

```
data[['HomePlanet', 'CryoSleep', 'Transported']].dtypes
```

```
HomePlanet      object
CryoSleep      boolean
Transported    boolean
dtype: object
```

I want to make a heatmap based on this pivot_table:

```
result_1 = data.pivot_table(columns='HomePlanet', index='CryoSleep', values='Transported')
result_1
```

```
HomePlanet  Earth   Europa  Mars
CryoSleep           
False   0.320992    0.400172    0.276982
True    0.656295    0.989023    0.911809
```

But when I try to build a heatmap with seaborn I get an error:

```
sns.heatmap(result_1, annot=True, cmap="PiYG_r")
```

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

I tried swapping columns and index in pivot_table but got the same error:

```
result_2 = data.pivot_table(index='HomePlanet', columns='CryoSleep', values='Transported')
result_2
```

```
CryoSleep   False   True
HomePlanet      
Earth   0.320992    0.656295
Europa  0.400172    0.989023
Mars    0.276982    0.911809
```

```
sns.heatmap(result_2, annot=True, cmap="PiYG_r")
```

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I build a heatmap based on pivot_table?

Comment: 0.11.2. Now I will update and try with the new version.

Comment: @JohanC Even with the latest version it doesn't work :(

Comment: Which numpy and pandas versions? What is `result_1.dtypes`? Which library throws the error? Can you include the full error trace?

Comment: @JohanC  I looked at the dtypes of result_1 and result_2 and the types were Float64. I changed all types to float64 and now the heatmap finally worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohanC Can you write an answer to the question so that I can accept it and close the question?

Comment: Good to hear you solved the problem. I'm still not sure about the real cause. It might be some version problems. Feel free to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohanC.
I looked at the dtypes of result_1 and result_2 and the types were Float64:

```
result_1.dtypes
```

Output:

```
 HomePlanet
Earth     Float64
Europa    Float64
Mars      Float64
dtype: object
```

I changed all types to float64 with this lines:

```
for column in result_1.columns:
    result_1[column] = result_1[column].astype('float64')
```

And now the heatmap finally worked!

Comment: this solved my exact problem, thank you!